# Is it allowed to enter in Disneyland Paris with food?

Tags: legal, food-and-drink, paris, disney

Last time that I've visited Paris I was able to go for Eurodisney and I saw some people with natural sandwiches on their bags, is it allowed to enter on Disneyland parks with some food? It's very expensive to buy inside the parks.

Comment: There's an FAQ about picnics and outside food, but it's not clearly stated. Big food containers or coolers, tables that you would need to a group picnic are not allowed. There are picnic tables outside the park entrance. They don't specifically say that outside food and drink is banned. Many people that they have brought in fruit, rolls, some drinks.

Comment: When I was last there (a few years back), they accepted people with some food in bags but not whole shopping bags full of food.

Answer (score 7):

I have found this post about it. It is in French but I'll translate the general idea behind it :
http://www.disneylandparis.fr/faq/restaurants/alimentation-boissons-exterieur/

So it isn't allowed to bring with you large bags full of food to organize a group picnic inside the park. They don't explicitly say that it is allowed to bring some water or sandwiches but as it isn't explicitly forbidden, then you can safely assume that this is implicitly allowed.

The general idea is that they want to avoid group of 10 people sitting around and starting a picnic in the middle of an area. But drinking your own water or even eating a sandwich is ok as long as you don't start using large spaces. Still, don't expect to have some free tables or seats inside the park to ease this...

Comment: [Here](http://www.disneylandparis.co.uk/faq/dining/outside-food-beverages/) is the English equivalent of that FAQ. It says that group picnics requiring special equipment like chilly bins, chairs etc are not allowed. There's a dedicated picnic area for this between the park entrance and the parking lot. However, bringing a few sandwiches and some drinks and snacks should be fine. Also worth noting: alcoholic beverages and glass bottles are prohibited, as per the [park's rules](http://holidays.disneylandparis.co.uk/legal/theme-parks-rules.html)

Comment: Great answers!! So I think that I should only be discreet and don't eat as a group.